# How to prevent "your computer went to sleep" chrome "crash"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

We have a dashboard which should refresh every 5min *if* the client is online.

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (navigator.onLine) location.reload();
}, 300000);
```

However, we constantly run into a chrome "crash-like" screen with different variations most commonly "your computer went to sleep":

[image: sleep]

What would be a good, reliable way to refresh *if and only if* we're up (awake) and online?

Comment: That's interesting!..  never seen that Chrome error.  Must admit don't put most computers I use to sleep..   I'm just wondering if this error is due to the computer been asleep and it building up setIntervals. eg.  5min into 12hrs = 144 missed setIntervals, and it's maybe that it's complaining about.  In this case, maybe a better idea is to use `setTimeout` instead,. And basically trigger another `setTimeout` after the previous one.  This then will maybe prevent 144 missed intervals been stacked up.

Comment: I've now dropped `setInterval` and just use a single `setTimeout` to reload the page once - which then runs the same thing again etc.. Same problem "The computer went to sleep" + FrownyFace :-(

Comment: In addition to the sleep stuff we see the same frownyface with some other error messages: `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` and, sometimes, `ERR_TIMED_OUT`.